# Backup for finisar.Sqlite database

Tags: c#

Am using Finisar.sqlite and C# language but backup has been difficult.

```
                using (var destination = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + " DatabaseBk.db; Version=3;", this.txtpath.Text)))
                {
                    SetConnection();
                    sql_con.Open();
                    destination.Open();
                    sql_con.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
                    sql_con.Close();
                }
                txtpath.Clear();
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Backup Completed Successfully", "MESSAGE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

It throws an error saying my connection does not contain a definition for 'BackupDatabase'.

Comment: Just had a look at the SQLiteConnection and that method does not exist. Where did you read it.

Comment: If your project is in .NET Core, you should use `System.Data.SQLite.Core` nuget package. `SqLiteConnection` class from this library has BackupDatabase method.

Comment: If you are using .NET Classic framework then you should use `System.Data.SQLite` nuget package. SqLiteConnection class from this library has BackupDatabase method.

Comment: Thank you, Chetan. It's working now. I was not using the right library.